# Web-services for private computer-assisted web interviewing

Tags: web-services, survey

I am looking for web-services preferably free ones that would allow me

1. Dispatch emails to known addresses to invite participants to complete a questionnaire
2. Design questionnaire by arranging checkboxes and fields for multiple questions, so that every participant could log in with own credentials and fill out all the boxes
3. the results of questionnaire completion for N people must be aggregated and be available for viewing by organiser in the form of report with votes distribution

The links are most welcome.